# Odd results in Joda DateTime for 3 July 1916 in Europe/Moscow time zone

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Joda doesn't allow to create an instance of DateTime in Europe/Moscow time zone pointed to 3 July 1916:

```
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
Chronology internalCalendar = GJChronology.getInstance(dateTimeZone);
DateTime dt = new org.joda.time.DateTime(1916, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, internalCalendar);
// Exception thrown:
// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition: 1916-07-02T21:30:00.000
```

Exactly period from 00:00:00 to 00:00:47 gives an exception.

AFAICS, there are no special timeshift events at the date in Russia. The closest date is 1 July 1917 when Summer time introduced at the first time.

Is this a bug in Joda or something wrong with me? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=166&year=1916) you can read that there was a time zone change on Monday, 3<sup>rd</sup> July 1916 on 0:00:00/0:00:48. The 48 seconds from 0:00:00 to 0:00:47 were skipped.

Comment: Just about to post the same link!

Comment: Does anyone know why? to move 2.30 and 48 seconds before GMT seems odd at a time when most time zones were trying to align with GMT. They moved to a more sensible 3.00.00 hours before GMT in 1919.

Comment: My google-fu was too weak, @James. I didn't find anything illuminating.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the link. I didn't find it.

Comment: @Daniel -- At about the same time Chile went 46 seconds off the GMT hour mark ( but only 14 seconds of on DST) weird or what.